# Creating a testing class for a strange program

Tags: java

I have completed my project, but cannot get the testing class to work. I know this is because i wrote the code in probably the worst possible way. However, it's too late to change now, and honestly i don't want too either. Could someone suggest a possible way of a testing class based on the code i currently have...

Comment: I don't think that even compiles.

Comment: Why are all your fields `static`? And you need a constructor.

Comment: You are posting alot of code without an error message. We cannot attempt what you want to do, but we can help you with errors in your code. For that you have to post them. This way at least I am clueless what answers you expect

Comment: you have absolutely no methods in Pizza and everything is static. There must be some code missing here. I don't see how you could test anything here.

Comment: The program runs and does what it should do. But, i can't do the testing class.. There are no error messages because it's the testing class i cannot do. My attempt is just a complete guess really, so the errors are not relevant

Comment: There is WAY too much code there, and you have [tag:static] absolutely everywhere. You may not be able to test it at all like this. Where are the Pizza methods?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is untestable. You need to use more object oriented way of programming. Try to refactor code into few shorter methods. Then you can test separate methods.

For unit testing I recommend [Junit](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your code might work because you extend `Pizza` and then in your main you just set the static attributes. But there is absolutely nothing you could test here, as you have 0 methods and 0 objects.

You can't even instantiate your `Pizza` class, as all its attributes are static and an instance would therefore be useless.

All you can test is assigning values to static attributes, but I guess we can expect that to be bugfree ;-)

Comment: What can i do to make the program testable =/

Comment: Start from scratch and use some OOP. Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/ And also read more tutorials on google if you need.

Comment: I can't, it's far too late for that now.

Comment: Any suggestions without being required to "Start from scratch"?

Comment: Not really sorry :/ You could try to remove all statics and actually use instances of Pizza instead. But that would require a lot of changes already